# How to get the first canonical correlation from sklearn's CCA module?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

In scikit-learn for Python, there is a module call cross_decomposition with a canonical correlation analysis (CCA) class.  I have been trying to figure out how to give the class 2 multidimensional vectors of shape (n,m) and get the first canonical correlation coefficient.  Looking off the documentation, a little example script is as follows.

```
from sklearn.cross_decomposition import CCA
import numpy as np

U = np.random.random_sample(500).reshape(100,5)
V = np.random.random_sample(500).reshape(100,5)

cca = CCA(n_components=1)
cca.fit(U, V)

cca.coef_.shape                   # (5,5)

U_c, V_c = cca.transform(U, V)

U_c.shape                         # (100,1)
V_c.shape                         # (100,1)
```

I do not really understand how to use this class to get the first canonical correlation between two matrices, which is all that I need.  It seems generally directed towards classification and prediction problems, but I just need the first canonical correlation coefficient and nothing else.  I know there are a few other posts somewhat similar to this, but the question remains unanswered and the best suggestion is to change to MATLAB, which is a non-solution.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your transformed matrices `U_c` and `V_c`, you can indeed retrieve canonical component correlations like you did, and more generally for a CCA with `n_comp` CCs:

```py
result = np.corrcoef(U_c.T, V_c.T).diagonal(offset=n_comp)
```

Now, you do not have to `tranform` your data yourself, it has been done during the fitting procedure at least for the training data. The score are stored in the `CCA` instance by scikit-learn, so:

```py
score = np.diag(np.corrcoef(cca.x_scores_, cca.y_scores_, rowvar=False)[:n_comp, n_comp:])
```

Will give the same result, a vector of `n_comp` scalar values, corresponding to the score, or correlations between each pair of canonical components.

Answer (score 3):

Well, with some help looking at the source code in [pyrcca](https://github.com/gallantlab/pyrcca/blob/master/rcca.py) I managed to create this snippet of code to get out the first canonical correlation.

```
cca = CCA(n_components=1)
U_c, V_c = cca.fit_transform(U, V)

result = np.corrcoef(U_c.T, V_c.T)[0,1]
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Note: The [pyrcca](https://github.com/gallantlab/pyrcca/blob/master/rcca.py) package mentioned above runs slightly quicker than sci-kit learn's, due to heavier usage of multi-core processing for anyone who was curious.  Also they have implemented kernel CCA unlike sklearn.

Comment: Hmm this might not be right.  I didn't test it enough and it seems to give invalid answers some of the time.

Comment: Hello, I wrote my own which does exactly this ... please try the following:
https://github.com/stochasticresearch/depmeas/blob/master/python/rdc.py

In this file, the **cca** function will do what you want.