# Calculating n-th Canonical Correlation and Coefficients with Python Scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

By consulting the scikit manual, this was found:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_decomposition.CCA.html

From googling I found that getting the first canonical correlation was to do this: [How to get the first canonical correlation from sklearn's CCA module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398856/how-to-get-the-first-canonical-correlation-from-sklearns-cca-module)

Does anybody have any idea how to calculate the canonical correlation coefficient with scikit? What about the first order canonical correlation, second order canonical correlation, etc.?

PS: Apparently, CCA hasn't been updated for a while (https://www.mail-archive.com/scikit-learn-general@lists.sourceforge.net/msg06029.html). Does anybody know its status?

Comment: Does anyone know the status of CCA?  I also saw https://www.mail-archive.com/scikit-learn-general@lists.sourceforge.net/msg06029.html, and am wondering if I should use this alternative (https://github.com/gallantlab/pyrcca) instead.

Answer (score 4):

Let `X`,`Y` be `n x d1` and `n x d2` matrices, where n is the number of observations. In order to get the different orders of canonical correlation  you need to initializing the CCA object using the following:

```
n_components = 3
cca = CCA(n_components)
cca.fit(X, Y)
U, V = cca.transform(X, Y)
```

U and V are n x n_components (3 in this example) matrices. Each column of U and V is a different order of correlation. In order to find the canonical correlation you need to do:

```
for i in range(n_components):
    corr = np.corrcoef(U[:,i], V[:,i])[0,1]
    print np.round( corr, 4)
```

I tried this method and it produced the same results as the Canonical Correlation Analysis package in R.

Answer (score 4):

## In short:

```py
cca = CCA(n_components=3)
cca.fit(X, Y)
cc_corr = np.corrcoef(cca.x_scores, rowvar=False).diagonal(offset=cca.n_components)
```

## Details:

This is now answered for correlations of any CC pairs in [How to get the first canonical correlation from sklearn's CCA module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398856/how-to-get-the-first-canonical-correlation-from-sklearns-cca-module).

[Vartholomeos Argiris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40832696/5303618)'s answer is correct but the loop is unneeded, although might be faster in some case, not so sure as my answer here do not use the `.transform` computation.

But I would like to put a clear answer explaining how to get the CC correlations **directly from the fitted CCA instance**, and to give some explanations about what is happening.

If you use the *same matrices* `X` and `Y` to fit and to get the correlations of CC, you **do not have to transform them**! Indeed (following OP's notations) `U` and `V` are simply stored in `cca.x_scores_` and `cca.y_scores_` respectively.

Then we want to get the correlation coefficient between each pair of columns in `U` and `V`. The output of a `np.corrcoeff(U, V, rowvar=False)` is (with slight abuse of notation, where I denote by `UtU` the correlation matrix of `U`, not a covariance matrix, and not the product of those two matrices either):

```
|  UtU    UtV |
|             |
|  VtU    VtV |
```

The above will be of size `2*n_components x 2*n_compoenents`, where:

- `UtU` (and `VtV`) is correlation matrix of `U` (so of each column of `U`) of size `n_components x n_components`
- `UtV` is the correlation matrix between columns of `U` and columns of `V`, on the diagonal of that block you will find correlations between matched column pairs (1st column of `U` with 1st column of `V`, 2nd column with 2nd column, and so on...) also of size `n_components x n_components`

All in all, you just need to take the diagonal of the correlation matrix between CCA's scores (`U` and `V`) with an offset of `n_components` to pick up the diagonal of the `UtV` block:

```py
cc_corr = np.corrcoef(cca.x_scores, rowvar=False).diagonal(offset=cca.n_components)
```